# How do you use ErrorHandler in specified lines

Tags: vba

I have one `ErrorHandler` at the start of my code (`On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`) and it works properly. But now I want to add several handlers (`ErrorHandler1` and `ErrorHandler2`) that each check specific lines in the code. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either overwrite the current handler or use a select case in a single handler.

with two handlers:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Long
    x = 0
    
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Debug.Print 5 / x
    On Error GoTo errorhandler2
    Debug.Print 5 / x
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number
    Resume Next
    
errorhandler2:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, "handler2"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

With a select case to handle errors based on the error received:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim x As Long
    x = 0
    
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Debug.Print 5 / x
    
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 11
        Debug.Print Err.Number
        Resume Next
    Case 1004
        Debug.Print Err.Number
        Resume Next
    End Select
End Sub
```